# How to manage permissions on a Samba mount

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, network-share, file-permissions

I have a Samba server (`nas01`) which presents a share called `downloads`. The permissions on that share are as follows:

`root@nas01:/mnt/storage/downloads# ls -al
drwxrwxr-x+   9 phil samba-users  4096 Aug 16 00:09 .
drwxrwxr-x    3 phil samba-users  4096 Aug 13 22:16 ..
drwxrwx---+ 231 phil samba-users 12288 Aug 15 00:56 Movies
drwxrwx---+  42 phil samba-users  4096 Aug 15 23:15 TV`

The users used to remotely access the Samba share are local users on the Samba server and are all in the group samba-users. Locally, on the Samba server itself, those users can access the files:

`root@nas01:/mnt/storage/downloads# sudo -u plex ls TV | wc -l
40`

When the share is mounted on another Linux server (`plex01`), this is how it appears:

`root@plex01:/mnt/downloads# ls -al
drwxrwxr-x+   9 phil 1001    0 Aug 15 23:09 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root 4096 Aug 18 20:09 ..
drwxrwx---+ 231 phil 1001    0 Aug 14 23:56 Movies
drwxrwx---+  42 phil 1001    0 Aug 15 22:15 TV`

The local `root` user can access it:

`root@plex01:/mnt/downloads# ls TV | wc -l
40`

But the local `plex` user cannot:

`root@plex01:/mnt/downloads# sudo -u plex ls TV
ls: cannot open directory TV: Permission denied`

If I create a local group with GID `1001` and add the `plex` user to it... then it can access the files.

`root@plex01:/mnt/downloads# ls -al
drwxrwxr-x+   9 phil plexrunner    0 Aug 15 23:09 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root       4096 Aug 18 20:09 ..
drwxrwx---+ 231 phil plexrunner    0 Aug 14 23:56 Movies
drwxrwx---+  42 phil plexrunner    0 Aug 15 22:15 TV`

`root@plex01:/mnt/downloads# groups plex
plex : plex plexrunner`

`root@plex01:/mnt/downloads# sudo -u plex ls TV | wc -l
40`

So, the question is... what is the right way to manage these permissions?

- Is there, for example, a way to mount the share such that local user permissions are not observed? This is an LXC container specifically for running Plex, so that is probably ok.
- Can local user permissions be applied to the share without them propagating up to the Samba server and affecting all clients?
- Am I missing something really obvious here..?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a way to match IDs (user or group) on server and client.  If you're not in an environment using a directory server and such, you can assign ownership through the group.  Export the folder with the group set for samba-users.  Make sure that the GID for the group is the same on server and client by creating the same group on all the clients and ensuring that the users are members of that group.  Set permissions for the folder and all the contents to the group.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost exactly the same setup at home. As security is not a concern, I just set my samba mounts to be anonymous and force the UID (and GID if needed) to the `plex` user like this, without any modifications to accounts on the server:

```
[downloads]
browseable = yes
path = /mnt/downloads
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 777
force user = plex
```

Where the mount point is owned by user `plex`. Clients may need to mount as `guest`, but after that will be fine.